# Exporting scheduled date to latex from org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

When I export scheduled work to pdf using latex from org mode, scheduled date and time is not exported. How can I get them on pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either configure `org-export-with-planning` or use

```
#+OPTIONS: p:t
```

in the document header (c.f. http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html).

Comment: Please summarize what that link adds to the answer and *explain* each of the alternative solutions you mention - say what it does and how that answers the question.